# SQL Server: Regenerate value for identity column on row update

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

`SequenceId` is an auto-incrementing identity column, but isn't the primary key.

What I want to happen is that when a row is updated, `SequenceId` is set to the next available  value, e.g.:

```
_____________________
| SequenceId | Name |
| 1          | John |
| 2          | Jane |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

Update John to Jack. `SequenceId` is set to the next available identity value.

```
_____________________
| SequenceId | Name |
| 3          | Jack |
| 2          | Jane |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

Is this possible with SQL Server? If not, what would be an alternative?

Comment: You cannot do this - an `IDENTITY` column cannot be updated - only inserted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can, at least not easily or cleanly.  Why not use a [ROWVERSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) column?  ROWVERSION columns are updated every time the row is updated to a new unique incrementing value in the database.  You can create a computed column that converts it to a bigint if you want to index it.  The downside is that timestamps are database-wide so you could get skipped numbers if you have multiple tables that use them.

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6988a/2)

```
create table TestRowVersion (
    Id int primary key,
    Name varchar(20),
    BinaryRowVersion ROWVERSION,
    IntegerRowVersion as convert(BIGINT, BinaryRowVersion)
)   

create index IDX_TestRowVersion on TestRowVersion (IntegerRowVersion)

insert into TestRowVersion (Id, Name) values (1, 'Alvin')
insert into TestRowVersion (Id, Name) values (2, 'Betsy')
insert into TestRowVersion (Id, Name) values (3, 'Charles')
select * From TestRowVersion
update TestRowVersion set Name = 'Frank' where Id = 2
select * From TestRowVersion
```

*[EDIT] - updated to use RowVersion since Timestamp is deprecated*

Comment: Wow, the timestamp data type (alias rowversion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) is a brilliant solution for what I'm trying to do. Thanks Jason!

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to happen is that when a row is updated, SequenceId is set to the next available value...

That's not enough, you also want to update the sequence generator, so the next inserted value will be correct.

If you are using MS SQL Server 2012, you can explicitly use the [sequence object](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/sequence-object-in-sql-server-2012.html), instead of the implicit IDENTITY. This allows you to generate the next sequence number without INSERT, like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MySquence AS INT START WITH 0;

CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    SequenceId INT DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR MySquence),
    Name VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO MyTable (Name) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name) VALUES ('Jane');

SELECT * FROM MyTable;

    SEQUENCEID  NAME
    1           Jane
    0           John

UPDATE
    MyTable SET SequenceId = NEXT VALUE FOR MySquence,
    Name = 'Jack'
WHERE Name = 'John';

SELECT * FROM MyTable;

    SEQUENCEID  NAME
    2           Jack
    1           Jane
```

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e75f9/1)

---

On older versions, you can emulate the sequence by having a separate table, containing a single IDENTITY column and then:

- insert a new row into that table and get the resulting auto-incremented number using `INSERT..OUTPUT` (or `@@IDENTITY`),
- then you can immediately delete the row to save storage.

---

Or, if you don't have any referential integrity to care about, you can "update" the row by deleting and inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table] ON

UPDATE [table]
SET Name = 'some name',
    SequenceId = MAX(SequenceId) + 1
WHERE ID = 123

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table] OFF
```

Comment: I added the IDENTITY_INSERT, which I am not totally sure works on update, but I would think so.

Comment: The `IDENTITY_INSERT` will work then you **INSERT** a new value into a column with `IDENTITY`. It does **NOT WORK** for `UPDATE`